# Values not binding properly to Select Option in jsp using enhanced for loop

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, foreach

The select option value are dynamically bind in jsp page but the if the first value is `Views`
all other option value are becoming Views like wise, if the value is `Edit` then all become `Edit` can't able to fix the problem, in this `plevel` is the `arrayList` it has either `Edit` or `Views` value, help me to find the solution....

```
<select id="change">
    <% for (Object level : plevel) { 
        if (level.equals("Views")) { %>
            <option><%=level%></option>
            <option>Edit</option> 
        <%} else if (level.equals("Edit")) {%>
        <option><%=level%></option>
        <option>Views</option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
}
```

This is my output image
[image: This is my output image]

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting

Comment: @sankrish Like above only i am getting

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you assist me with this problem, I am voluntarily involving you...

Comment: @Selva post the rendered output for `select` html & expected output `select` html. Why are you closing the `select` inside the `for` loop. How muche `select` boxes need to be printed?

Comment: @vjy ony two select box at once need to be printed, the values are coming from `action class struts1.3.10` the 1st value has `Views` and 2nd value has`Edit` but displaying both as `Views` then 2nd select should display as `Edit` but not this is my problem

Comment: @Selva if you need two `select` boxes, you should not nest them inside a single for loop, you need to have separate iteration for each `select` box.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the comment , you need 2 select boxes , do something like this , this could print one select box at a time for each object . If you need to have separate ones try as @vjy mentioned

```
    <% for (Object level : plevel) { 
        if (level.equals("Views")) { %>
            <select id="change1">
            <option><%=level%></option>
            <option>Edit</option> 
            </select>
        <%} %>   
        <% else if (level.equals("Edit")) { %>
             <select id="change2">
            <option><%=level%></option>
            <option>Views</option> 
            </select>
        <%} %>   
   <%}%>
```

**Update:**

using jstl you could do it easily

```
         <c:forEach var="temp" items="${plevel}">
                    <c:if test="${temp eq 'Views'}">
                    <select id="change">
                       <option>${temp}</option>
                    </select>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${temp eq 'Edit'}">
                    <select id="change2">
                       <option>${temp}</option>
                    </select>
                    </c:if>
         </c:forEach>
```

Try the above code , wrap the html separately from scriptlets . Also look into 
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: while copy paste form my code i forgot to paste it here, but i mentioned in my original copy of my code... even though having same problem....

Comment: Have you checked what `plevel` contains . this need to be done in the server side . you should have sent two lists separately

Comment: yes I had checked already data in server side has no issue while displaying only has the issue

Comment: @selva will update my answer using `jstl` . try that

Comment: no without `tld` I want to get the output this is my task

Answer (score 0):

If you need two `select` boxes you should not nest them inside a single `for` loop. Try with this code.

```
<select id="change1">
        <% for (Object level : plevel) { 
            if (level.equals("Views")) { %>
                <option><%=level%></option>
                <option>Edit</option> 
            <%} %>   
      <%}%>
</select>

    <select id="change2">
        <% for (Object level : plevel) { 
            if (level.equals("Edit")) { %>
                <option><%=level%></option>
                <option>Views</option> 
            <%} %>   
       <%}%>
</select>
```

It is always better to use `jstl` instead of writing `java` code in jsp